# OpenAPI Swagger - Empty-Valued and Nullable Parameters

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

How can [Empty-Valued and Nullable Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) such as query param `metadata` in a route such as `GET /foo?metadata` be documented in [@nestjs/swagger](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger)? Using either `readonly metadata?: null;` or `readonly metadata?: null;` in a route `@Query()` dto class prompts the user in the generated swagger to enter a `string` value for the `metadata` property. This is confusing because no value is meant to be passed to this query param. Also trying `@ApiProperty({ required: false, default: true, nullable: true }) readonly metadata?: boolean` provides a dropdown but does not add the `Send empty value` checkbox that would be in swagger/oas3.

In Swagger/OAS3 this would be documented as:

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: metadata
    schema:
      type: boolean
    allowEmptyValue: true
```

The key here would be the property `allowEmptyValue`. How can `allowEmptyValue` be defined in a TypeScript class representing a `@Query()` dto either through `@nest/swagger` decorators or [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) decorators? It looks like [BaseParemeterObject](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/1dd0b3ea5291243d5fafc73a563f46da7238a2ce/lib/interfaces/open-api-spec.interface.ts#L112) has the property `allowEmptyValue: boolean`, but how can that be used with an individual query dto param property?

**Update:**

I am able to use `ApiQuery()` decorator on a route in a `@Controller()` as follows to get the correct functionality:

```
@ApiQuery({ name: 'metadata', allowEmptyValue: true, type: Boolean, required: false })
```

But how could I get that same functionality in a a `class` DTO representing the `Query()`?

Comment: Same issue with allowEmptyValue, it sends no value that breaks validation.